# How to record Roland Juno DS sounds onto a computer

Tags: recording, synthesizer, garage-band, mac

I've been able to connect my JUNO DS-88 to my computer and can play and record sounds that GarageBand gives me. But I want to record sounds that my JUNO gives me, so if someone could tell me how in a clear explanation that would be great.

Comment: I think this question is answered here: https://superuser.com/questions/1149721/how-can-i-record-audio-to-wav-format

Comment: Here's the correct link for audio-over-USB on the Juno DS: https://www.roland.com/us/support/knowledge_base/207935966/

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that you are currently using a USB cable to connect the keyboard to the computer. When you hook it up this way, you are using the keyboard as a "controller" - that is, you are sending MIDI information from your keyboard to control the digital instruments in GarageBand.

Your Juno DS-88 can also send audio over that USB cable (not all keyboards can do this, though). Here are the instructions from the Roland website:

> Connecting your Juno-DS61/88 to a computer using the direct USB connection
>
> 1. On the Juno-DS61/88, press MENU.
> 2. Cursor to "SYSTEM" and press ENTER.
> 3. Use the  buttons to select the "MIDI" tab at the top of the screen.
> 4. Cursor to "USB Driver" and set this to "Vender."
> 5. If prompted, cursor to "WRITE" and press ENTER to save this setting, then power off and back on the Juno-DS61/88.
> 6. Download and install the Juno-DS61/88 USB driver for your computer and connect the USB cable. You can download the latest drivers from our website here.
>
> Note: If you are using a Windows 10 computer, the driver will automatically be downloaded and installed when you conned the Juno-DS61/88 to your computer via USB.
>
> Make sure you download the driver that corresponds to the type of computer you have (Mac or Windows-based) and the version of operating system you are using. Once downloaded, you will need to run the setup application to install the driver into your system. This may include re-starting your computer.
>
> 7. Confirm that the USB driver is installed correctly and that the computer is communicating correctly with the Juno-DS61/88.
>      •On a Macintosh, look in the Audio MIDI Setup utility and confirm that the Juno-DS61/88 is listed in both the Audio and MIDI Studio windows.
>      •On a PC, open the Device Manager and confirm that the Juno-DS61/888 is listed under "Sound, video, and game controllers."
> 8. Activate or enable the Juno-DS61/88 in your music software. You will need to consult with the documentation for your specific application for this, but usually there is a preferences menu where you will need to enable the Juno-DS61/88 so it can be used by your software.
>
> This will allow you to transfer both MIDI and Audio data between the Juno-DS61 or Juno-DS88 and your computer.
>
> https://www.roland.com/us/support/knowledge_base/207935966/

Comment: The Juno DS range has audio-over-USB functionality.

Comment: @YourUncleBob I've updated the answer to include your suggestion.