# How do I get Logic Pro X to record the audio from my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, midi, daw, logic-pro, audio

I have all the necessary cables to do this, however I'd like to know how to get it going.

Comment: What do you mean “get it going”? Besides push the record button?

Comment: What type of keyboard? If you give us the model that may help. Are you 100% sure it's not just a midi controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to record Roland Juno DS sounds onto a computer](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/80314/how-to-record-roland-juno-ds-sounds-onto-a-computer)

Comment: read below -----

Comment: Sorry, I just realized how vague my question was. I have A Juno DS88, which should be able to send audio data. I also have Logic Pro X on my mac. I've been able to use it like a MIDI controller, but I'm trying to record the sounds my Juno gives me onto my computer.  I think it's something to do with what I need to do in my DAW so if there are any Logic users around that would be  or even if you're not.